# What Does This Ember Exception Mean?

Tags: exception, ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting the following error when creating a new record/model:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `willSetProperty` on <App.NewsItem:ember361:null> while in state rootState.loaded.created.inFlight. Called with {reference: [object Object], store: <App.Store:ember299>, name: bodyHTML}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Could you provide an example on jsbin.com?

Comment: Unfortunately it's specific to a local API, so I can't.

Comment: I don't have worked with ember-data, but I think that your problem is the same described in that article http://coryforsyth.com/2013/06/27/ember-buffered-proxy-and-method-missing/. Your are changing the model while its saving the data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be caused by the application updating a property (called 'bodyHTML') on an instance of a model of type `App.NewsItem` while it is being saved (`rootState.loaded.created.inFlight`). I have no idea why I'm receiving the error on creation though.

Comment: It's impossible to know what's going on without seeing the code. But I suspect you might be iterating through the controller's `content` property to display a list of items and that `App.NewItem` would insert a record in the content upon creating. If that's the case, try creating computed property that returns only the items in `content` which are already syncd.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I appreciate it's difficult without the code, but I was hoping for some clues. I couldn't even find any references to what `inFlight` meant. Having dug deeper, the problem seems to be that I was creating a Model and immediately saving it, but whilst the save was happening, the Models template was added to DOM, causing its view's `didInsertElement`hook to fire which called a jQuery library function on one of the elements in the view that had a `valueBinding` set up. The lib altered the element's value, causing the model to update whilst it was still saving, causing the exception.

Comment: @Pedr In that case, you might be able to simply wrap that template with something like `{{#unless isSaving}}` to prevent it from being rendered at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like either you are modifying an existing dirty object , or you are trying setting some property to undefined

see

> http://coryforsyth.com/2013/06/10/the-willsetproperty-gotcha-in-ember-data-understanding-the-state-machine/